# About Event Loop: how promise work with synchronous script

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

Commonly, we think that promise create a microtask, and add it to microtast queue. Once the call stack is empty, microtask will been push into call stack.

But what makes me confused is this example:

```js
console.log(1)

Promise.resolve().then((res) => {
  console.log(2)
})

console.log(3);
```

In my opinion,I think it works as this:

```js
console.log(1) //push into call stack

// console log: 1  (pop from call stack)

//so now call stack is empty
Promise.resolve().then((res) => {  //here we create a microtask into microtask queue, 
                                   //and stack is empty,
                                   //but it not push into call stack, why???
  console.log(2)   //no console now
})

console.log(3);  //console log: 3

//console.log: 2
```

So I'm must wrong, but which step is my wrong, and what is the exactly rules.

Comment: I'm still looking for the correct terminology :p - actually call stack IS the correct term - but don't forget, that code you have in the question is in the call stack - so the call stack isn't empty until after `console.log(3);` completes

Comment: so when it log 1 in the console, the `console.log(1)` will not pop immediately, right?

Comment: Pop what. That whole code block is in the call stack. Something called it

Comment: You could say that the `console.log` lines (1,3) and the `promise.then` are part of the stack of the script. Your `promise.then` pushes a new item into the queue (the scheduling function itself is running on the script stack). The script stack doesn't exit until script finishes completion. Then the new item on the queue gets a new stack and the `console.log` line with 2 gets run.

Comment: thanks! I get you. the `stack frame` in call stack is not a single statement, but a block.

Comment: There's more information about the queue and stack [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: thank you very much, Jaromanda and Minus !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Jaromanda X and @MinusFour. I found where my mistake is:

```js
//this block will push into call stack

//------- a block --------
console.log(1) //console log: 1

//so here the block is still in stack.
Promise.resolve().then((res) => {  //create a microtask
  console.log(2)
})

console.log(3); //console log: 3
//------------------------

//here the block is pop from call stack.
//so call stack is empty now

//so microtask push into call stack
//console log: 2
```

The most important thing is that javascript **block** is the basic `stack frame` in `call stack`, *instead of a single statement*.